# Agile PLM Unable to extract {0}, see the log for details

Tags: oracle-agile-plm

I am new to Agile PLM,

I am getting error like Unable to extract {0}, see the log for details message in ATO's. 
Can anyone help me to resolve this and root cause for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Log to Javaclient and try to do Destination reset.
2. Please check for space on your managed servers. Generally when it is more than 80% occupancy on server this error comes.

Third approach you can do is :

1. Disable all the Subscribers.
2. Test destination if it works or not.

4th Approach :

If you are having a clustered environment. You can check ACS configurations : 
if ACS.Skips = True in all the server then it's not ideal scenario. It should be true only on one.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above suggestions, if your issue is still not resolved, you can try to check if any exception is occurring during extract. I hope, if you are using any clustered environment, ACS is enabled in only one managed server. So expecting that, check out the STDOUT log of the particular managed server (if using WLS) where the ACS is enabled. If the WLS managed servers are installed as Windows Service you need to edit the registry entries for each of them & modify the server start up parameters for each of them to set **ACS.Skipserver=true** in all but one.

Now, to print the logs, you need to log in to web client, go to tools & settings  -> Administration --> Logging configuration --> Set the following entries to **DEBUG**:

1. com.agile.acs.PCExtractTask
2. com.agile.acs.ScheduleMaster
3. com.agile.acs.ScheduledEventTask
4. com.agile.extract.server
5. com.agile.extract.server.ExtractService